# converting JSON object to nsdictionary from nsstring on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

We are trying to convert the JSON object from NSSTRING TO NSDICTIONARY but we are not getting any  value. Here is the url  for our webservice http://ecreeds.info/theappsoluteguideto/appservice.asmx/appArea

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSONLint.com it appears your webservice returns a 500 error for the response hence why you are not seing anything, because of invalid json

Comment: Thanks for reply, We are getting following JSON object when we debug the variable on xcode  ... [{"RowNumber" : "1","AreaId" : "3","Area" : "Maharastra"},{"RowNumber" : "2","AreaId" : "4","Area" : "Madhya Pradesh"}];

Comment: I would recommend you use SBJSON http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/  NSError *error = nil;
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 NSDictionary *jsonArray = [parser objectWithString:[request responseString] error:&error];
 [parser release];

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't valid. In fact, it's quite off.